# Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<', 'firebase' is not define

Tags: javascript, firebase, syntax-error

So when I deploy a simple firebase html page to front end hosting site, it shows errors for all js link

I researched and found that may be issue with redirect to html, but couldn't find out why.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-performance.js"></script>
    <!-- 
      initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
      to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
    -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="message">
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      <h1>Firebase Hosting Setup Complete</h1>
      <p>
        You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting.
        Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!
      </p>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/"
        >Open Hosting Documentation</a
      >
    </div>
    <p id="load">Firebase SDK Loading&hellip;</p>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const loadEl = document.querySelector("#load");
        // // 
        // // The Firebase SDK is initialized and available here!
        //
        // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { });
        // firebase.database().ref('/path/to/ref').on('value', snapshot => { });
        firebase
          .firestore()
          .doc("/foo/bar")
          .get()
          .then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
              console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            } else {
              // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
              console.log("No such document!");
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
          });
        // firebase.functions().httpsCallable('yourFunction')().then(() => { });
        // firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(() => { });
        // firebase.storage().ref('/path/to/ref').getDownloadURL().then(() => { });
        // firebase.analytics(); // call to activate
        // firebase.analytics().logEvent('tutorial_completed');
        // firebase.performance(); // call to activate
        //
        // // 

        try {
          let app = firebase.app();
          let features = [
            "auth",
            "database",
            "firestore",
            "functions",
            "messaging",
            "storage",
            "analytics",
            "remoteConfig",
            "performance",
          ].filter((feature) => typeof app[feature] === "function");
          loadEl.textContent = `Firebase SDK loaded with ${features.join(
            ", "
          )}`;
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          loadEl.textContent =
            "Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console.";
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> ''' Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' '''
>
> ''' Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined '''

Comment: Firebase import should be before closing the `</body>` and you only need to  import the dependencies you need.

Comment: @BorisDetry but this index.html is auto-generated by firebase, how come it doesn't works?  it works when you deploy to firebase hosting, but it doesn't works when you deploy to other web front end hosting site, please advise, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This import only exists on using Firebase Hosting or its emulator in the Firebase CLI:

```
<script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>
```

This `init.js` file contains the configuration data for your Firebase project, which is something other hosting providers won't know anything about.

So when running this app on another hosting provider, you will have to explicitly define the configuration by copy/pasting it from the Firebase console. For details on how to do this, see the <kbd>From the CDN</kbd> tab in [Step 3: Add Firebase SDKs and initialize Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize). For reference: you've now followed the <kbd>From Hosting URLs</kbd> step from the same section.

Comment: OMG thank you so much, this have bother me so much for the past few days, I just can't figure out why it doesn't work on other hosting site.Thank you , I wish firebase documentation can have more clarity for this situation